# How to fix "Property 'type' is missing in type but required in type 'SeriesXrangeOptions'" in angular highcharts module

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I am trying to display a price chart view of selected cryptocurrency in cryptocurrencies list view but I am getting type mismatch error.

I have used angular-highcharts module in my application and imported Chart library from that module .

```
import { Chart } from 'angular-highcharts';

series: [{
  name: 'Price',
  data: [{
    id: this.comparearray[0].symbol,
    name: this.comparearray[0].name,
    y: this.comparearray[0].quotes.USD.price
  }]
},
{
  name: "Volume_24h",
  data: [{
    id: this.comparearray[0].symbol,
    name: this.comparearray[0].name,
    y: this.comparearray[0].quotes.USD.volume_24h
  }]
}]
```

I am getting the below error in all of the above lines :

---

> Type '{ name: string; data: { id: any; name: any; y: any; }[]; }' is
>   not assignable to type 'SeriesAbandsOptions | SeriesAdOptions |
>   SeriesAoOptions | SeriesApoOptions | SeriesAreaOptions |
>   SeriesArearangeOptions | SeriesAreasplineOptions |
>   SeriesAreasplinerangeOptions | ... 82 more ... | SeriesZigzagOptions'.
>
> Property 'type' is missing in type '{ name: string; data: { id: any;
>   name: any; y: any; }[]; }' but required in type
>   'SeriesXrangeOptions'.ts(2322) highcharts.d.ts(339172, 5): 'type' is
>   declared here.

---

I should get a chart view of the selected cryptocurrency showing the volume over 24hrs and price.

Comment: What is `comparearray`?

Comment: comparearray is an array which has been declared inside the component.

Answer (score 6):

Also received the same "SeriesXrangeOptions" error, however `xrange` was not a valid type option.  Specifying the series chart type worked for those who receive an invalid type error.

Working example:

```
chart = new Chart({
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Linechart'
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'line',
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [1, 0, 4, 6, 11]
    }, {
        type: 'line',
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 7, 3, 2, 9]
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 6):

when you are using multiple series in your charts you need to mention the type of the series. Simply changing your code to this works sometimes:

```
 series: [{
  name: 'Price',
  type:undefined,
  data: [{
    id: this.comparearray[0].symbol,
    name: this.comparearray[0].name,
    y: this.comparearray[0].quotes.USD.price
  }]
},
{
  name: "Volume_24h",
  type:undefined,
  data: [{
    id: this.comparearray[0].symbol,
    name: this.comparearray[0].name,
    y: this.comparearray[0].quotes.USD.volume_24h
  }]
}]
```

Do Give it a try once. I hope this helps to solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
new Chart({YOUR_OPTIONS} as any);
```

It will fix the error.

Answer (score 2):

```
Property 'type' is missing in type '{ name: string; data: { id: any; name: any; y: any; }[]; }'
```

> but required in type 'SeriesXrangeOptions'.ts(2322) highcharts.d.ts(339172, 5): 'type' is declared here.

The error is about missing property in the `Series` object in your code. [In TypeScript the `type` option must always be set.](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.type)

So, the correct code will be like:

```
series: [{

  type: 'xrange`,

  name: 'Price',
  data: [{
    id: this.comparearray[0].symbol,
    name: this.comparearray[0].name,
    y: this.comparearray[0].quotes.USD.price
  }]
},
{

  type: 'xrange`,

  name: "Volume_24h",
  data: [{
    id: this.comparearray[0].symbol,
    name: this.comparearray[0].name,
    y: this.comparearray[0].quotes.USD.volume_24h
  }]
}]
```

assuming that you want to set `xrange` as the series type for both series. (And you could skip the extra empty lines - added just to better show the changed code)

The same issue reported and resolved on the Highcharts github, for reference: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/9867

Comment: I gave the type as 'xrange' in my price chart component and the error were gone. But in browser console, I receive the error "
PricechartComponent.html:3 ERROR Error: Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17

Comment: This error occurs probably because you haven't load `xrange` module, have you?

Comment: the error occurs in the below line in price chart html file.      <div [chart]="chart"></div>

Comment: Can anyone help here?

Comment: @amitabha What error? What HTML file? Please provide more info. You could edit the question, so it will be clearer what's the problem about. Also, a live demo will help.