# US Counties map in Highmaps for Angular throws compilation error

Tags: angular, highcharts

I'm trying to deploy US Counties map in Highmaps using the `highcharts-chart` directive. This works fine with the US States map, but have a problem defining the data element for US Counties as I get a compilation error.

This is the attempt:

HTML

```
    <highcharts-chart 
        [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
        [constructorType]="'mapChart'"
        [options]="chartMap"
        [(update)]="updateFlag"
        [oneToOne]="true"
        style="width: 500px; height: 400px; display: block;"
    ></highcharts-chart>
```

Typescript

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import MapModule from 'highcharts/modules/map';
const mapX = require('@highcharts/map-collection/countries/us/us-all-all.geo.json')
MapModule(Highcharts);

.....
.....
this.chartMap = {
                chart: {
                    map: mapX
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'THIS IS THE US COUNTIES MAP'
                },
                series: [{ // <-- error is thrown here
                    name: 'Unemployment',
                    borderWidth: 0.5,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                        color: 'red'
                        }
                    },
                    joinBy: ['hc-key', 'code'],
                    data:  [  
                        {
                            "code": "us-al-001",
                            "name": "Autauga County, AL",
                            "value": 3.9
                        },
                        {
                            "code": "us-al-003",
                            "name": "Baldwin County, AL",
                            "value": 4.3
                        }
                    ]
                    }]
            };
```

I get the following compilation error:

> Type '{ name: string; borderWidth: number; states: { hover: { color:
>   string; }; }; joinBy: string[]; data: { "code": string; "name":
>   string; "value": number; }[]; }' is not assignable to type
>   'SeriesAbandsOptions | SeriesAdOptions | SeriesAoOptions |
>   SeriesApoOptions | SeriesAreaOptions | SeriesArearangeOptions |
>   SeriesAreasplineOptions | SeriesAreasplinerangeOptions | ... 82 more
>   ... | SeriesZigzagOptions'.   Property 'type' is missing in type '{
>   name: string; borderWidth: number; states: { hover: { color: string;
>   }; }; joinBy: string[]; data: { "code": string; "name": string;
>   "value": number; }[]; }' but required in type
>   'SeriesXrangeOptions'.ts(2322) highcharts.d.ts(335083, 5): 'type' is
>   declared here.

I took the data example from [here](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highcharts/highcharts@c116b6fa6948448/samples/data/us-counties-unemployment.json) and the map example from [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/us-counties/).

What is this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs because you haven't set the series `type` which is required for each series when using TypeScript.

```
series: [{
  name: 'Unemployment',
  type: 'map', // type is required for each series
  borderWidth: 0.5,
  states: {
    hover: {
      color: 'red'
    }
  },
  joinBy: ['hc-key', 'code'],
  data: [{
      "code": "us-al-001",
      "name": "Autauga County, AL",
      "value": 3.9
    },
    {
      "code": "us-al-003",
      "name": "Baldwin County, AL",
      "value": 4.3
    }
  ]
}]
```

More information about this issue:

- [How to fix "Property 'type' is missing in type but required in type 'SeriesXrangeOptions'" in angular highcharts module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54670687/how-to-fix-property-type-is-missing-in-type-but-required-in-type-seriesxrang)
- https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/9867

Comment: Thanks, now I'm getting this error: `Type '{ "code": string; "name": string; "value": number; }' is not assignable to type 'number | [string, number] | SeriesMapDataOptions'.
          Object literal may only specify known properties, and '"code"' does not exist in type '[string, number] | SeriesMapDataOptions'.ts(2322)`. I need the name for the map, how to fix this?

Comment: The error above is thrown when using the Angular wrapper. I switched (due to several reasons, this is one of them) to using Highmaps directly without the wrapper, and the error went away.

Comment: Could you reproduce it?